# Error parsing script @mdt2/cl_mdt.lua in resource mdt2: @mdt2/cl_mdt.lua:16: 'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 5) near elseif

Tags: lua, fivem

The line of code the error is talking about is the line below (they are line 4 through 22) And i can't wrap my head around what the problem could be, so i came here asking for help. I would be really grateful if you could help.

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
while true do
    Citizen.Wait(0)
    local playerPed = PlayerPedId()
    local playerVeh = GetVehiclePedIsIn(playerPed, false)
    if not isVisible and IsPedInAnyPoliceVehicle(playerPed) and IsControlJustPressed(0, 311) and GetEntitySpeed(playerVeh) < 10.0 then
        if GetVehicleNumberPlateText(getVehicleInFront()) then
            TriggerServerEvent("mdt:performVehicleSearchInFront", GetVehicleNumberPlateText(getVehicleInFront()))
        end
    elseif IsControlJustPressed(0, 163) then
        TriggerServerEvent("mdt:hotKeyOpen")
    end
elseif not IsPedInAnyPoliceVehicle(playerPed) and not IsPauseMenuActive() then
    TriggerServerEvent("mdt:hotKeyOpen")
end
if DoesEntityExist(playerPed) and IsPedUsingActionMode(playerPed) then -- disable action mode/combat stance when engaged in combat (thing which makes you run around like an idiot when shooting)
    SetPedUsingActionMode(playerPed, -1, -1, 1)
end
```

end)

Comment: Your loop would run infinitely as there's no `break` BTW. I assume the `elseif` was supposed to be part of the `if`-chain inside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

```lua
while true do
...
elseif not IsPedInAnyPoliceVehicle(playerPed) and not IsPauseMenuActive() then
    TriggerServerEvent("mdt:hotKeyOpen")
end
```

A loop has no else/elseif branch.